# Timeout when offline iOS (using waitsForConnectivity)

Tags: ios, swift, networking, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Whilst implementing several HTTP calls, I noticed some strange behaviour on the URLSession. As far as I know, URLSession data tasks used to immediately throw an error when the network connection was unavailable (error -1009 The Internet connection appears to be offline).

I'm now performing network requests too, and while executing a request in flight mode, the request runs for as long as the timeout, before failing. I tried creating a custom configuration that should prevent this, but this does not work. How can I re-enable or configure the behaviour where a request will immediately crash when there is no connection?

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.waitsForConnectivity = false
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 2
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 0

URLSession(configuration: config).dataTask(with: url) { d, r, e in
    print(d?.count, (r as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, e?.localizedDescription)
}.resume()
```

The [configuration documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/2908812-waitsforconnectivity?language=objc) appears to be inconsistent or incorrect.

Comment: @ElTomato I suggest you read the linked documentation page. Expected behaviour does not occur

Comment: @Bram any luck with it?  Note my answer FWIW

Comment: @Fattie no, unfortunately not. I've never managed to get this to work at all. There's not been any response on the Apple developer forum either

Comment: @Bram Right.  My guess is that the two ".timeout.." properties ... have nothing to do with anything, In typical Apple style :)

Comment: Copied this URL configuration and ran it on the simulator. The call exited immediately, even when I bumped the timeout to 10.

Answer (score 2):

the `async/await` `data(from:url` works as expected error is thrown right away.

```
do{
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.waitsForConnectivity = false
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 2
    config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 0
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    print("call")
    let (data, response) = try await session.data(from: url)
    
    print("Done")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I can duplicate the issue with `dataTask(with: url)` so I think it is worth a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

One factoid I've found.

Even in the latest Xcode/iOS (2024), the feature seems to **not work at all in simulator**.

In simulator the `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, taskIsWaitingForConnectivity task: URLSessionTask)` will work, but nothing else works,

i.e. it **never tries again**, when bandwidth is back, regardless of any settings.

Comment: The `async/await` version seem to work as expected.